# SD Card partition named differently on different devices - breaks music player

Tags: external-sd, music, file-system

I have recently moved from a Droid 2 to Droid 3, both running Android 2.3. The same SD card registers as "sdcard" on the D2, and "sdcard ext" on D3. Probably for this reason, I am having problems with music files, as well as playlists. When I move the SD card back to the D2, it is in the "sdcard" folder. In the D3, it is in the "sdcard ext" folder. I would like to know:

1. why is this different?
2. where are the music playlist files typically stored?

Answer (score 1):

Your new device has a small amount of internal memory and a large amount of storage memory. This larger section is termed as `/sdcard` and the contents of a physical microSD card inserted into your device is assigned the label `/sdcard_ext` or similar.

The android media scanner will intelligently scan thru your entire sd card (both if you have a physical card inserted too) at boot time.

You can place your music files in the following folders. YMMV due to differing versions of Android.

`/sdcard/Music/` - Media scanner classifies all media found here as user music.

`/sdcard/Podcasts/` - Media scanner classifies all media found here as a podcast.

`/sdcard/Ringtones/` - Media scanner classifies all media found here as a ringtone.

`/sdcard/Alarms/` - Media scanner classifies all media found here as an alarm sound.

`/sdcard/Notifications/` - Media scanner classifies all media found here as a notification sound.

`/sdcard/Pictures/` - All photos (excluding those taken with the camera).

`/sdcard/Movies/` - All movies (excluding those taken with the camcorder).

`/sdcard/Download/` - Miscellaneous downloads.