# How to Use Camera in ICS to store images on internal memory?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, camera, hardware

The SD card slot on my HTC Dezire Z is broken and a replacement is not available. How can I use my camera without an SD Card? I am using ICS.

Answer (score 1):

You need a device with both internal and external memory. If your device have two different mounting points, then you have internal memory. One is for your (now damaged) SD slot, and the other is for the internal memory. Folder names shoul be /mnt/sdcard and /mnt/extsd ([actual names may vary depending on the device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16982/sd-card-partition-named-differently-on-different-devices-breaks-music-player)).

You have two options:

1. Change the default storage for your pics. On Android 4.0, open your camera app, click on the "options" icon, there are 3 options, exposure / balance / settings, the first setting is "local storage", turn it on
2. Use a new camera app with options on where to save the photos you take. I love **[camera360](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vStudio.Android.Camera360&hl=pt_BR)** because of its amazing filters, and you can shoose where to save the photos

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my phone doesnt have these two.. it only has /mnt/sdcard.
I downloaded Camera 360 but it also cant help. The default location for my fone is /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera. Can i change this?
When I try to edit the path it only goes to /sdcard folder and not outside. :(

Comment: @dmk Even if you have no SD card connected, can you access your /mnt/sdcard folder and there are any files there? If so, then you are already viewing your intenal memory.

Comment: Is your device rooted? If so, you could simply create the `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera` folder. As ruda correctly states, this would then be in internal memory. Though without a sd card inserted, the `/mnt/sdcard` folder *might* not even exist (the system might create it "on-demand"), so you've had to create it yourself and set the appropriate permissions for your apps to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution is to go external... There was recently a successful social funding campaign for MicroSD card readers that connect to the microUSB port of Android phones. http://www.meenova.com/